# How to get autostart permission through a simple dialog box (Android)

Tags: android, whitelist, autostart

Some brands like Xiaomi, Oppo, Vivo, Honor etc don't allow apps to run service/broadcast receiver etc in background until we whitelist the app by doing things like providing 'Autostart' permission. To make the user give Autostart permission to  the app, my app  takes the user to Settings screen where they can enable Autostart for the app. I think doing this might make the user suspicious of my app, or they may feel intimidated.
Is there  a way to get Autostart permission through a dialogbox, or is there  an alternative way to whitelist the app other than getting Autostart permission?

Right now I'm using this code:

```
 if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("xiaomi")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new

                    ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",
                    "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));

            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("oppo")) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                        "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClassName("com.oppo.safe",
                            "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                                "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception exx) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But it takes the user to the Autostart screen in Settings, which I don't want.

Please suggest a way to get Autostart permission through a dialogbox, or other way to Whitelist app through a simple dialogbox.